# UWP Webview InvokeScriptAsync passes wrong argument to JS function

Tags: windows-phone-8.1, windows-mobile, uwp

In my JS file I have **handleMessage(message)** function. 
The message argument looks like "background=/path;".

Problem is that when I call **InvokeScriptAsync("handleMessage", new[] { "background=/path;" }**
I just got a "general" as argument in JavaScript.

If I replace "background" to something else the parameter in JS is going to be correct. 
This issue is only valid for Mobile. I have no issues on desktop.

Comment: you can invoke eval. Something like: 
`InvokeScriptAsync("eval", new[] { "handleMessage('background=/path;')" };`

Comment: I now get "general" string as a parameter on the desktop also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I just got a "general" as argument in JavaScript.

I'm curious how did you know that you got a "general", did you output your `message` on your html? It looks like you set an file path to the `background`, one problem here is whether the file path is legal in an UWP app, since UWP app works in sandbox, some paths which can be used in classic desktop apps can't be used in UWP.

I can't reproduce your issue base on your poseted code both in UWP app and WP8.1 app, I just assumed that you want to set an image to the background of an element. Here is a sample:

```js
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>WebViewInvoke</title>
    <link href="css/default.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function handleMessage(message) {
            var element = document.getElementById("textbody");
            element.style.background = message;
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body id="textbody" style="color:black; background:url('Assets/1.jpeg')">
    <div>Content goes here!</div>
    <script src="js/main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

This is my html file and as you can see I invoke the function `handleMessage` inside this html file, it is the same if you put this function into the js file.

So when calling `InvokeScriptAsync` method, we can use `Uri` to get the image's path as following:

```cs
string[] specs = { "url('Assets/2.jpeg')" };
await webView.InvokeScriptAsync("handleMessage", specs);
```

Basically the main idea here is that you can try to use `Uri` to replace your `path`, and my images are saved in the `Assets` folder of the project. If you have any question here, please update your code and leave a comment.

Comment: Thanks! "general" string was my mistake (we had some JS code which was specific to windows phone and did these strange things). But we replaced path with `url` and it helped.